# Spring Integration DSL: How to add the HTTP.outboundGateway header?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

What is the easiest way to add the `HTTP.outboundGateway` header in my program?

What I want to do is:

I first do the `HTTP GET` for the `URL`

```
http://localhost:8050/session
```

then I get the JSON

```
{
   "session": "session8050"
}
```

I extract the value of the `session` variable and add that to the next `HTTP GET`as the `session` header variable.

Currently I have working code, but I was thinking could I do this easier? My implementation

1. Extracts the `session` variable from the JSON with the `jsonPath` method
2. Then the implementation adds the `session` variable to the integration flow message header with the `enrichHeaders` method
3. Then the implementation adds the `session` variable to the HTTP call header with the `HeaderMapper` class

   My implementation is

   ```
   integrationFlowBuilder
   .transform(p -> authenticationJson)
   .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("Content-Type", "application/json"))
   .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8050/session").httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
           .expectedResponseType(String.class))
   .enrichHeaders(
           h -> h.headerExpression("session", "#jsonPath(payload, '$.session')", true)
   .handle(Http
           .outboundGateway(completeFromUrl)
           .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET).mappedRequestHeaders("session").headerMapper(headerMapper())
           .expectedResponseType(String.class))
   ```

My `headerMapper` is

```
@Bean
HeaderMapper headerMapper() {
    final DefaultHttpHeaderMapper headerMapper = new DefaultHttpHeaderMapper();
    final String[] headerNames = { "session" };
    headerMapper.setOutboundHeaderNames(headerNames);

    headerMapper.setUserDefinedHeaderPrefix("");
    return headerMapper;
}
```

Is it possible to extract the session variable from the JSON and add it straight to the HTTP headers??

Why the `HeaderMapper` must be used? Why the integration flow message headers don't go straight to the `HTTP.outboundGateway` call as the payload goes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to understand that main goal of Spring Integration as any other EIP solution is to make components in the flow as isolated as possible, so in the future you can add some intermediate steps or remove without big impact for the whole solution and other components in your integration flow. This should be an answer to your questions about why `HeaderMapper` must be used.

As you see the contract of the `HeaderMapper` to remap `MessageHeaders` to the target protocol headers representation. There is nothing about `payload`, hence you need to map the value from the `payload` into the headers, first of all. And then say `Http.outboundGateway()` what should be remapped from the `MessageHeaders` into the `HttpHeaders`.

By default the `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` (it is present there in the `Http.outboundGateway()`) maps only standard HTTP headers suitable for the HTTP request.

If you need to include some custom header, like in your case with that `session`, you really can use a custom configuration for the `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper`, or just configure a convenient option on the `Http.outboundGateway()`:

```
.mappedRequestHeaders("session")
```

The `setUserDefinedHeaderPrefix("")` is not necessary from version `5.0`. It is empty string by default now, since there is no requirements in the prefixes for custom headers in the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Thanks! This gave more background information about the model.